# pip installing a tar.gz file from remote github repo

Tags: git, github, pip, package, setup.py

I wrote a python package for work, which I originally published to PYPI. Everything worked perfectly, I could pip install and use all the modules I wrote. All was well. After a few minutes, I realized that there may be sensitive info in the package, so unpublished it, silly me/new dev stupidity.

Then I decided the easiest method would be to take the `tar.gz` file -- generated in the `dist` folder when running `python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` -- and add that to my company's private github repo.

I added the file, committed, and then tried the following command:

```
pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/company_github/my_repo.git@commithash
```

And get the following error message:

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/me/opt/anaconda3/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/78/bn32jmyx0350cdp7cc_3t2ym0000gn/T/pip-req-build-qqbm6_ox/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/78/bn32jmyx0350cdp7cc_3t2ym0000gn/T/pip-req-build-qqbm6_ox/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/78/bn32jmyx0350cdp7cc_3t2ym0000gn/T/pip-req-build-qqbm6_ox/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /private/var/folders/78/bn32jmyx0350cdp7cc_3t2ym0000gn/T/pip-req-build-qqbm6_ox/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/tokenize.py", line 447, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/var/folders/78/bn32jmyx0350cdp7cc_3t2ym0000gn/T/pip-req-build-qqbm6_ox/setup.py'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

What exactly am I doing incorrectly? Do I need to add my `setup.py` file to the same folder housing my `tar.gz` file? Or is there something I need to do with the requirements file --> can't be installed until all dependencies are installed?

Is it possible to `pip install` the tarball directly? I gave that a shot too,

```
pip install https://github.com/company_github/my_repo/my_package.tar.gz
```

But got an `ERROR: HTTP error 404` saying the file could not be found.

Any help or direction is much appreciated!

EDIT:

Here is the file structure:

```
    .
    ├── CF_dev_emr_cluster.yaml
    ├── DeepAR\ Model\ Input\ Check\ (json).ipynb
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── anomaly
    │   ├── MAD.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── batch_transform
    │   ├── batch_transform.py
    │   ├── generic_batch_transform.py
    │   ├── get_time_series_as_rows.py
    │   └── post_batch_transform.py
    ├── dev_env
    │   ├── CF_dev_emr_cluster_m5d.yaml
    │   ├── CF_dev_emr_cluster_r5d.yaml
    │   └── new_cluster_v2.sh
    ├── digital_logging.py
    ├── hive_table_checker
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── hive_table_checker.py
    ├── metadata_io
    │   ├── README.md
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── manage_metadata.py
    │   ├── model_record_example.py
    │   └── tests
    │       ├── __init__.py
    │       └── test_manage_metadata.py
    ├── parquet_converter
    │   ├── CF_parquet_emr_cluster_m5d.yaml
    │   ├── DAGs
    │   │   ├── monthly_parquet_convert_v1.5.py
    │   │   ├── monthly_parquet_convert_v1.6.py
    │   │   └── utils
    │   │       └── check_partitions.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── dist_parquet_converter.sh
    │   ├── dist_parquet_copy.sh
    │   ├── dist_spark_parquet_converter.sh
    │   ├── parquet_config.json
    │   ├── parquet_converter.py
    │   ├── parquet_emr_connection_update.sh
    │   ├── parquet_final_copy.sh
    │   ├── parquet_start_stack.sh
    │   ├── patef_schema.json
    │   ├── ptef_schema.json
    │   └── readme.md
    ├── pyspark_visualizer
    │   └── visualizer.py
    ├── readme.md
    ├── setup.py
    ├── testfile.txt
    └── tests
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── airflow_testing
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   └── dag_test
        │       ├── __init__\ 3.py
        │       ├── __init__.py
        │       ├── test_dag_pytest\ 2.py
        │       └── test_dag_pytest.py
        ├── config.py
        └── test_airflow_dags.py

    13 directories, 49 files
```

Comment: You can upload the tar to [releases](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/about-releases) and install using the direct link.

Comment: Your second method should work. The URL is probably wrong, did you check? It might be something like https://github.com/company_github/my_repo/blob/master/my_package.tar.gz

Comment: So I also tried that method as well: 'ip install https://github.com/company_github/my_repo/blob/master/mypackage.tar.gz'
And still get a `HTTP error 404`. But when I go to that link, it exists in the github repo. So I wasn't quite sure why that was happening.

Comment: Is this repository public. Can you still download the `.tar.gz` file when you are logged out of your account in the browser?

Comment: It's a private repo as well. I wouldn't be able to download it without having ssh-rsa key access, which my github account is set up pull from my company's

Comment: I guess you need to configure _pip_ so that it can use your credentials to access the URL. Probably something like `pip install https://USERNAME:PASWWORD@github.com/company_github/my_repo/my_package.tar.gz`.

Comment: hello @sanjayr, just wondering did you find the solution to pip install `.tar.gz` from private git repo ?  would you mind sharing if you found, thanks